# batch file to read file contents and iterate

Tags: linux, bash, shell, flyway

I am trying to write a batch file/shell script that reads the contents of a file, matches those contents with a directory structure and invokes an executable file.

Let's say there is a sequence.txt file in /system/ directory. The sequence file is to represent or force the order of execution. This is important

The sequence.txt file has following enteries:

```
1;schema1;procedures
1;schema1;functions
2;schema2;procedures
2;schema2;functions
........
```

and then there is a directory, and the directory has following subdirs

```
/scripts
|  +--/schema1
|  |  +--/procedures
|  |  |  --1.sql
|  |  |  --2.sql
|  |  +--/functions
|  |  |  --1.sql
|  |  |  --2.sql
|  |  +--/packages
|  |  |  --1.sql
|  |  |  --2.sql
|  |  +--/logs
|  +--/schema2
|  |  +--/procedures
|  |  |  --1.sql
|  |  |  --2.sql
|  |  +--/functions
|  |  |  --1.sql
|  |  |  --2.sql
|  |  +--/packages
|  |  |  --1.sql
|  |  |  --2.sql
|  |  +--/logs
.......
........
```

Now I would like to run flyway (a database migration software) in a loop using this way:

```
Flyway -schema=schema1 -locations=/scripts/schema1/procedures, /scripts/schema1/functions, /scripts/schema1/packages migrate -x | tee /scripts/schema1/log/logfile_ddmmyy.log

Flyway -schema=schema2 -locations=/scripts/schema2/procedures, /scripts/schema2/functions, /scripts/schema2/packages migrate -x | tee /scripts/schema2/log/logfile_ddmmyy.log
```

So far this is my progress:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read i; 
    do echo "$i"; 
done < ./system/sequence.txt
```

How can I proceed further? I know that this kind of scripting involves variables and then loops but I can't find a way to translate it into technical level.

Cheers and thanks in advance! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though not completely clear about what you want, here is some inspiration:

```
while read line; do
    OIFS=$IFS
    IFS=';'
    a=()
    for name in ${line}; do
        a+=(${name})
    done
    IFS=$OIFS
    number=${a[0]}
    schema=${a[1]}
    subdir=${a[2]}
    echo "Flyway -schema=${schema} -locations=/scripts/${schema}/procedures, /scripts/${schema}/functions, /scripts/${schema}/packages migrate -x | tee /scripts/${schema}/log/logfile_ddmmyy.log"
done <<EOF
1;schema1;procedures
1;schema1;functions
2;schema2;procedures
2;schema2;functions
EOF
```

It doesn't exexute Flymake, it just `echo` the Flymake commands.

It uses the special variable [`$IFS`](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/$IFS) to do the magic.

Fit it to your needs.

**output**

```
Flyway -schema=schema1 -locations=/scripts/schema1/procedures, /scripts/schema1/functions, /scripts/schema1/packages migrate -x | tee /scripts/schema1/log/logfile_ddmmyy.log
Flyway -schema=schema1 -locations=/scripts/schema1/procedures, /scripts/schema1/functions, /scripts/schema1/packages migrate -x | tee /scripts/schema1/log/logfile_ddmmyy.log
Flyway -schema=schema2 -locations=/scripts/schema2/procedures, /scripts/schema2/functions, /scripts/schema2/packages migrate -x | tee /scripts/schema2/log/logfile_ddmmyy.log
Flyway -schema=schema2 -locations=/scripts/schema2/procedures, /scripts/schema2/functions, /scripts/schema2/packages migrate -x | tee /scripts/schema2/log/logfile_ddmmyy.log
```

Comment: Thank you, this is just what I needed :-)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the exact relation betwen values and final command path but awk is the tool to construct the call. Use somethin like:

```
c = `echo $i | awk -F ";" '{print "flyway" $1 "_" $2}'
```

where $x is the position of the value and you can construct a string.

After that you can run the c var with

```
`echo $c`
```

That should work.

UPDATED:

If I understand correctly what you need, you have to set two whiles, one inside the other. Something like this:

```
cat tt.txt | awk -F";" '{print $1}'| sort -u | while read i
do
 sc = `grep $i tt.txt | head -n 1 |  awk -F";" '{print $2}'`
 pt1 = "Flyway -schema=" $sc " -locations="
 pt3 = " -x | tee /scripts/" $sc "/log/logfile_ddmmyy.log"
 grep $i tt.txt | while read j
 do
  c=`echo $j | awk -F";" '{print $2}'| sort -u`
  pt2 = $pt2 "/scripts/" $sc "/" $c ""
 done
 echo $pt1 $pt2 $pt3
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I guess I wasn't very precise. 
My question is about matching the values from semicomma delimited file with the directory structure. Then create the URL, and the creation is to be done according to the sequence in file, and feed it to the program.